# It is illegal to name software releases after pop-culture things?

Tags: intellectual-property

An example: version 2.0 of a software is named "Thresh", version 2.1 is named "Cassiopeia", and so on? (taking names from a single source)

Comment: Why are these “pop culture”? Thresh is what you do after you harvest west and Cassiopeia is a name from Greek or Roman mythology.

Comment: These names are from League of Legends champions.

Comment: They might be *used* in LoL but they aren’t *from* LoL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is permitted so long as it doesn't violate a valid trademark or service mark (or a few equivalent rights in names that are comparable such as collective rights to market beef under the name "Waygu" only if it is produced in a certain area of Japan under Japanese law) that covers goods or services of the same type in the same economic market.

A trademark arises either when a term acquires a "secondary meaning" associating its use in connection with a particular kind of good or services in a particular market with a particular provider of that good or that service, or by registration of the trademark or service mark.

"Tresh" and "Cassiopeia" are not terms that inherently are related to software, so they are permissible to use as trademarks for software unless someone else already has established trademark protection for them.

Comment: ... even though Cassiopeia is a mythological figure, and a constellation, etc?

Comment: @paulgarrett If the goddess wants to sue, she can try. But she wasn't a software package. If you want to name your animated dog Pluto, however, there will be hell to pay (pun intended).

Comment: :) :) ...........